# Why body of html page does not extend to full width in Edge and IE but is ok for all other browsers?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a [webpage](https://staging.hobbydeed.com/#/public/group/hobbydeed/our-story) under development. Let's forget the contents. It is not relevant. It looks fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but it does not extend to full width in Edge or Internet Explorer.

[image: Contents not extending to page width]

If I write in their consoles (with the help of jQuery)

```
$('body').width($(window).width())
```

the body extends to the full screen width and is ok again. I have been trying to debug the page via console, but have not managed to find the reason.

DOM of the page in the reference acts as a source.

This happens only when screen width is above 990 (due to the media queries I use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS selector `.svg` that is being applied to your `html` element is is telling it to be an inline element with `display: inline-block;`. If you remove the `display` property from `.svg` or change the value to `block` the page will fill the browser viewport appropriately.

The CSS selector in question.

```
.svg {
  display: inline-block; /* <= the problem */
  background: 0 0;
  border: none;
}
```

From what I can tell you're using Modernizr to do some feature detection and it added the `.svg` class to `html` and you create your own `.svg` for some other purpose not knowing that Modernizr added `.svg` to `html`.

If the above is true then change/rename/override the CSS selector. If changed/renamed update the elements that originally used `.svg`.

Comment: Sorry for the specific question that didn't solve any general problem, but I have wasted a lot of time in searching for the answer from my code and this solved it immediately.